# Avoid browser print dialog with javascript

Tags: javascript

is there any way to capture the browser's print event and cancel the appearance of the print dialogue?

Example:

```
User clicks in "File" -> "Print". 
Before the print dialog appears, show a confirm() like 'It is possible that not all data is printed, continue anyway? <accept> <cancel>
User clicks <accept> -> Print dialog appears
User clicks <cancel> -> Print dialog doesn't appear
```

Right now I have this:

```
var beforePrint = function(ev) {
if (!messageShown) {
  var result = confirm('Are you sure?');
  if (!result) {
    // TODO: Cancel
  }
}
};
var afterPrint = function(ev) {
  // TODO
};

if (window.matchMedia) {
  var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
  mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
    if (mql.matches) {
      beforePrint();
    } else {
      afterPrint();
    }
  });
}

window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
```

Comment: No modern browser will allow you to *prevent* print functionality. And rightly so.

Comment: @RGraham: It might be possible that they did offer some kind of confirm box like the OP wants and e.g. the `beforeunload` event does; but you're right - they dont for `print`.

Comment: If you have layout issues, try a specialized print stylesheet that pretty much hides everything but your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to cancel it. Just call `window.print()` if they click on accept. If they use cntrl-p or file->print that's beyond your control anyway programmatically. BTW it should be noted that you actually can't do anything to prevent the user from manually trying to print. That includes intercepting their attempt to spawn the dialog and stop it from showing. The best you can do is apply a stylesheet to printing by default and then dynamically change that print stylesheet to enable the content's visibility when they use your code to print.

Comment: You *could* intercept `Ctrl+P`

Comment: can you add some example ?